# How to send a local file using Twilio?

Tags: python, twilio, mms

[Twilio's API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) provides a way of sending attachments or media in a text message using the `media_url` parameter. However it looks like `media_url` has to be a file hosted on an HTTP server. It breaks when you try to send it a local URI.

While I could just host the file I want to send publicly on the server, sometimes this file could be dynamic.

Is there a way to send the file contents through the API, or will I have to create some unique file in the public dir of my site and then use that for the media url?

Comment: @ShawnMehan That implementation is specific to Flask.

Comment: Yep. Read the second comment and it gives you your answer. You have to pass the Twilio API a URL, which using a Flask provides.